# ValueError: Invalid format string ejecutando script python en windows

Tags: python, script

Me sale el siguiente error ejecutandolo desde windows :

```
File "pandora_digitalocean.py", line 275, in <module>
    print_agent(agent, modules)
  File "pandora_digitalocean.py", line 57, in print_agent
    write_xml(xml, agent_name)
  File "pandora_digitalocean.py", line 165, in write_xml
    Utime = datetime.now().strftime('%s')
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

Este mismo script en maquina linux si me corre, el problema es con la expresion regular?

Comment: No sabremos cual es el problema si no vemos el código,  edita tu pregunta añadiéndolo

Answer (score 1):

No existe el formato `'%s'` para `strftime()`. Ver [Formatos para strftime() and strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%s')
ValueError: Invalid format string
>>>
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%S')
'27'
```

Comment: Eres grandísimo. Solucionado.